# Android-SharedPreferences with EditText which created with For Loop

Tags: android

I created EditTexts with "for loop" and I want to save datas from EditText with using SharedPreferences. I can manage this with creating EditTexts via xml but this takes lots of time and efforts. Below you can see codes.With second "for loop" i have been creating 15 EditTexts (numbers will increase) and I want to store datas from those EditTexts for some calculations. How can I use SharedPreferences with "for loop" for those EditTexts?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ScrollView sV;
    private LinearLayout pnl;
    private GridLayout gL;
    private TextView tV;
    private Button btn;
    private EditText eT;

    private void init() {

        sV = new ScrollView(this);
        hsV = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        pnl = new LinearLayout(this);
        pnl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        gL = new GridLayout(this);
        gL.setColumnCount(2);

        final String[] title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
        final String[] info = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.info);

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

            tV = new TextView(this);
            tV.setText(title[j]);
            tV.setTextSize(20);
            tV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            tV.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorText));
            gL.addView(tV);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

            tV = new TextView(this);
            tV.setText(info[i]);
            tV.setTextSize(20);
            tV.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorText));
            gL.addView(tV);

            eT = new EditText(this);
            eT.setTextSize(20);
            eT.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            gL.addView(eT);

        }

        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Save");
        gL.addView(btn);

        pnl.addView(gL);
        sV.addView(pnl);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
        setContentView(sV);

    }

}
```

Comment: `I want to store datas from those EditTexts for some calculations`, so what data do you want to save for each EditText?

Comment: I'm an agriculture engineer. (Above) for this example EditTexts represent amount of fertilizers. There will be also more EditTexts for ratio for each fertilizers. Each EditTexts can be changed by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add tags on your EditTexts to identify them.

You can then use these tags as keys in your SharedPreferences, something like that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  eT = new EditText(this);
  eT.setTextSize(20);
  eT.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

  // adding a tag to identify the EditText
  String tag = "edit" + i;
  eT.setTag(tag);

  gL.addView(eT);
}
```

How to store

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
  // get values
  String key = (String)editable.getTag()
  String value = editable.getText().toString()

  // save in SharedPreferences
  sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(key, values)
  sharedPreferencesEditor.commit()
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more?